# responsive layout with iframe and sidebar

Tags: css, reactjs, iframe, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a responsive layout containing a 16/9 iframe and a sidebar next to it but I can't seem to figure out how to do that and it's driving me crazy.I'm thinking it's caused by the iframe being 16/9. The 2 elements don't have the same height and when the screen gets smaller in width the iframe becomes alot smaller than the sidebar. This is the code i'm using:
the page layout code :

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import useGetLiveDetails from "../Signup/hooks/useGetLiveDetails";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import SideBarButton from "./SideBarButton";
import SideBar from "./SideBar/SideBar";
import Loader from "../components/Loader/Loader";
import useSocket from "./hooks/useSocket";
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge";

const LivePage = () => {
    const { token } = useParams();
    const liveData = useGetLiveDetails(token);
    const data = liveData.data?.live;
    useSocket(data?.id);
    if (liveData.isLoading) return <Loader />;
    return (
        <main className={twMerge(` flex min-h-screen flex-col  bg-secondary `)}>
            <Header title={data?.title} livePage={true}>
                <SideBarButton />
            </Header>

            <div className="flex h-full w-full flex-col items-center gap-4  p-3 lg:flex-row">
                <iframe
                    src={data?.url}
                    allowFullScreen
                    className=" aspect-video h-full w-full   rounded-lg border-0 outline-none"
                    title="Live"
                ></iframe>

                <SideBar liveId={data?.id} />
            </div>
        </main>
    );
};

export default LivePage;
```

this is my sidebar code:

```
import { useStore } from "../../store/store";
import { TabId } from "../store/store";
import Chat from "./Chat/Chat";
import Details from "./Details";
import QuestionToAnswer from "./Questions/QuestionToAnswer";
import Questions from "./Questions/Questions";
import Tabs from "./Tabs/Tabs";
interface IProps {
    liveId: number | undefined;
}
const TabToRender = (activeTab: TabId, liveId: number | undefined) => {
    switch (activeTab) {
        case 1:
            return <Chat liveId={liveId} />;
        case 2:
            return <Questions liveId={liveId} />;
        case 3:
            return <Details liveId={liveId} />;
        case 4:
            return <QuestionToAnswer liveId={liveId} />;
        default:
            return null;
    }
};
const SideBar = (props: IProps) => {
    const showSideBar = useStore((state) => state.showSidebar);
    const activeTab = useStore((state) => state.activeTab);
    const Tab = TabToRender(activeTab, props.liveId);
    if (!showSideBar) return null;
    return (
        <div className={` h-full  rounded-lg bg-primary lg:h-[calc(100vh-12vh)] lg:w-96`}>
            <div className=" w-full rounded-se-lg rounded-ss-lg bg-[#272424] ">
                <Tabs />
            </div>
            <div className=" h-full  p-2 lg:h-[calc(100%-11vh)]">{Tab}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SideBar;
```

here is an image of what i'm having now:
any help is appreciated.

[image: example of the layout]

Comment: could you maybe take out the javascript and put an working example at play.tailwind? you can add a empty box for the chat.

Comment: @RicardoSilva, thanks for the reply, here is the link : https://play.tailwindcss.com/HWGOZtSf6u the problem i'm having only occurs on larger screens, smaller screens there will be only one column.

Comment: I suspect this is an issue with the aspect ratio of the iframe, try adding self-start to the iframe class, that should make it at least stick to the top if the height can't be matched